# Flutter AppBar adding white border

Tags: flutter

Trying to create a custom navigation bar at the top of the screen. Currently with the below code I'm getting a white border around my nav bar. Anyway to fix this? I've evaluated it's not the actual header as if it's in the body of the scaffold it fits 100% to the size.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
Widget body = Body();
Widget header = Header();

return new Scaffold(

    appBar: new PreferredSize(
      preferredSize: Size(1000.0, 1000.0),
      child: new Card(
        child: header
      )),
    body: ListView(
      children: [
        body
      ],
    )
  );
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Card widget](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Card/margin.html) by default sets all its margins to 4.0. Override that value in your build method and you should be good:

```
child: new Card(
  margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
  child: header
)
```

Comment: Wow can't believe I missed that. Thanks a lot this should definitely fix it.